# I need help inputting a column from excel in VBA with html macro.

Tags: html, vba, excel, insert

I selected 2 cells and named them "perch" and "stats". using what i inputted in the cell, i was able to run a search and retrieve the data i wanted from the html code(which i changed for safety). But my problem is want to input an entire column not just a single cell. And produce multiple results in a single column. Also the number of inputs will change periodically ~300, so i can't stipulate a specific range.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Row = Range("perch").Row And _
 Target.Column = Range("perch").Column Then
     Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
     'IE.Visible = True
     IE.navigate "http://"google/not_real_link"
Do
 DoEvents
  Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
  Set Doc = IE.document
  Dim sTD As String
  sTD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(33).innerText)
  IE.Quit
  Range("stats").Value = sTD


 End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll usually see the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event used instaed of the `Worksheet_Change`.

Here are some tips on using these events:

- Turn off EnableEvents.  If you don't you might re-trigger the event and get stuck in an infinite loop
- Use the `Intersect` method to test to see if your range and the Target intersect.
- You should use Target.Cells.Count to see if multiple cells are being effected.

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("perch")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

```
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

End Sub

I'm not really sure how you want to handle multiple values.

Creating a function to add value(s) to the end of a list often helps.

```
Sub AddStatusRow(value As Variant)
    Const StatColumn = 5
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Range(Cells(1, StatColumn), Cells(Rows.count, StatColumn)).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Cells(lastRow, StatColumn) = value

End Sub
```

You might want to consider iterating over the rows of the table instead of `Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(33).innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of great examples of what you want to do from the URL below.

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_web_pages_services/index.htm